# Can I use formula as a SUM argument

Tags: excel, sum

Let's I have values on columns A and B from row 1 to 4. I want to sum the results of the multiplication An*Bn, like this:

=A1*B1+A2*B2+A3*B3+...+An*Bn

Since my index n is too great I was wondering whether there's an easier way to get this sum done, something like this:

=SUM((A1*B1):(A1000*B1000)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Vandre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A1000,B1:B1000)
```

This formula sums all the product values from a1 to a1000 and b1 to b1000

Hope it will help for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this would be to create a third column that does the multiplication:

C1's Forumula: **=A1*B1**

Then copy the C1 forumla down the entire C column.

Then SUM C:  **=SUM(C:C)** *or* **=SUM(C1:C1000)**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4;B1:B4)

A   B   C=(A*B)
1   1   1
2   2   4
3   3   9
4   4   16
        30  sum of C1:C4

30  =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4;B1:B4)
```